# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded - Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-tree

While implementing `add_node` and `search` methods for a binary tree, Im getting a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Code:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def add_node(self, node, value):
        node = self.root
        if node is not None:
            if not node.value:
                node.value = value
            elif not node.left:
                node.left = value
            elif not node.right:
                node.right = value
            else:
                node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)

    def search(self, value):
        node = self.root
        found = False
        while node is not None:
            if node.value == value:
                found = True
            if node.left:
                found = node.left.search(value)
            if node.right:
                found = found or node.left.search(value)
        return found



def main():
    binary_tree = BinaryTree()
    binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 200)
    binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 300)
    binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 100)
    binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 30)
    binary_tree.traverse_inorder(binary_tree.root)
    print(binary_tree.search(200))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\binary_tree_test20.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\binary_tree_test20.py", line 45, in main
    binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 30)
  File ".\binary_tree_test20.py", line 22, in add_node
    node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)
  File ".\binary_tree_test20.py", line 22, in add_node
    node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)
  File ".\binary_tree_test20.py", line 22, in add_node
    node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: I don't understand how `add_node` is supposed to work. Why are you setting the node's value to itself? Why don't the first three cases use the `value` parameter at all?

Comment: Does `add_node` really need to take both `node` and `value` parameters? It seems like it should just take `value`, and create the `TreeNode` object to contain it always.

Comment: How are you deciding where to add node in binary tree - left or right?

Comment: @Poojan left then right, at each level

Comment: @Barmar corrected code and error info

Comment: @user12916968 A binary tree should determine left or right depending on whether the new node is less than or greater than the current node.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `node` parameter if you're always replacing it with `node = self.root`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? if yes, how deep was the recursion when the error occurred?

Answer (score 2):

This is a remedy I can give you.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def _add_node(node, value):
    if not node.value:
        node.value = value
    elif not node.left:
        node.left = TreeNode(value)
    elif not node.right:
        node.right = TreeNode(value)
    else:
        _add_node(node.left, value)

class BinaryTree:
    # ...

    def add_node(self, value):
        node = self.root
        if node is not None:
            _add_node(node, value)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(value)

    # ...



def main():
    binary_tree = BinaryTree()
    binary_tree.add_node(200)
    binary_tree.add_node(300)
    binary_tree.add_node(100)
    binary_tree.add_node(30)
```

Although I recommend only extending `TreeNode` definition without defining `BinaryTree`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting infinite recursion because you're not using the `node` parameter, you're replacing it with `self.root`. So when you recurse, you start at the root again each time, and never end.

Also, the line `node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)` expects `add_node` to return the new node, but your method doesn't return anything. When it's updating an existing node it should just return the modified node; if it's creating a new node, it returns that node.

```
    def add_node(self, node, value):
        if node is not None:
            if not node.value:
                node.value = value
            elif not node.left:
                node.left = value
            elif not node.right:
                node.right = value
            else:
                node.left = self.add_node(node.left, value)
            return node
        else:
            return TreeNode(value)
```

You would call this method like this:

```
binary_tree.root = binary_tree.add_node(binary_tree.root, 30)
```